# Any suggestions for a responsive grid that will adapt text size and layout for different browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have been looking at some different systems. All the well known ones such as 960 etc. All seem like they were designed a few years ago and not many help me to change text sizes.

Can anyone suggest some products that feel are more up to date. Some code that will still be good to use in 5 years from now. Something that I can integrate easily with my jQuery MVC application.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [BootStrap](http://goo.gl/N3WK6) from twitter. It's fairly new and developed by some engineers at Twitter. It's updated regularly and does have support for responsive layouts